# custom authentication in oracle apex login page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Custom authentication in code is not working. Could you help me to fix this?

This is code I used:

```
create or replace function "MY_AUTHENTICATION"
    (p_username in VARCHAR2,
    p_password in VARCHAR2)
    return BOOLEAN
    is
        l_user sign_up.user_name%type := upper(p_username);
        l_id   sign_up.user_name%type;
        l_hash sign_up.set_password%type;
        begin     
            select user_name, set_password 
             into l_id, l_hash
             from sign_up
             where user_name = l_user and set_password = l_hash;
end;
```

and same procedure but it showing the following error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPwwX.png)

Answer (score 1):

`NO_DATA_FOUND` means you didn't find matching row in a table. Therefore, handle it in `EXCEPTION` handling section.

By the way, even if you didn't hit that error, you'd hit another: function must return some value; yours doesn't, in any case.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_AUTHENTICATION (p_username  IN VARCHAR2,
                                              p_password  IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
   l_user  sign_up.user_name%TYPE := UPPER (p_username);
   l_id    sign_up.user_name%TYPE;
   l_hash  sign_up.set_password%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT user_name, set_password
     INTO l_id, l_hash
     FROM sign_up
    WHERE     user_name = l_user
          AND set_password = p_password; -- not l_hash!

   RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
END;
```

Comment: i used the exception case now it is displaying the error like 
Invalid Login Credentials
Please wait 2 seconds to login again.

Comment: Which means that it works correctly. Provide valid username/password combination, i.e. then one that can be found in SIGN_UP table and Apex will let you connect.

Comment: This might be wrong: `AND set_password = p_password; -- not l_hash!`; I suggest you fix it.